# How to avoid ambiguous template instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm trying to define a class whose behavior varies in two ways, currently based on two different template parameters.
Originally I thought that template specialization simply augmented the primary class with functionality, and so my thought was to partially specialize the two arguments separately, in the hopes that this would make available all combinations.
Below is an example of what I tried to do:

```cpp
// specify the ways in which people can vary
enum class Weight { Skinny, Fat };
enum class Height { Short, Tall };

// primary class
template<Weight W, Height H>
struct Person
{
    const char* name = "name";
    void SayHello(void);
    void SayGoodbye(void);
};

// first specialize how a person says hello, based on their weight
template<Height H>
struct Person<Weight::Skinny, H>
{
    const char* goal = "ride a bike";
    void SayHello(void) {
        printf("Hello, I am skinny %s.\n", name);
        printf("My goal is to %s.\n", goal);
    }
};
template<Height H>
struct Person<Weight::Fat, H>
{
    const char* show = "movies";
    void SayHello(void) {
        printf("Hello, I am fat %s.\n", name);
        printf("My favorite show is %s.\n", show);
    }
};

// then specialize how a person says goodbye, based on their height
template<Weight W>
struct Person<W, Height::Short>
{
    void SayGoodbye(void) { printf("Goodbye, I am short %s.\n", name); }
};
template<Weight W>
struct Person<W, Height::Tall>
{
    void SayGoodbye(void) { printf("Goodbye, I am tall %s.\n", name); }
};
```

This does not work, because when I try to instantiate a `Person` as in

```cpp
Person<Weight::Skinny, Height::Short> X;
```

there is no uniquely most-specialized specialization, and (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization))

> If more than one specialization matches, partial order rules are used to determine which specialization is more specialized. The most specialized specialization is used, if it is unique (if it is not unique, the program cannot be compiled)
> The compiler says that

Clearly this is not a viable approach, but what would be a better solution?
I suspect that I am violating the single-responsibility principle somehow, but I'm not quite sure.
Any suggestions would be welcome.

Edit:

> Why do you need explicit instantation / specialization in 1st place?

Ultimately, the different specializations would also manage different sets of resources; I'm not sure if that's relevant, or a good reason.
(I recognize that what I tried to do would open the door to different specializations both declaring a variable of the same name, which I suppose is another reason this isn't meant to work.)
The main thing is to achieve all the combinations of height/weight, and I wasn't sure how to do that.

Edit:
Removed the solution I had added because the one from @rustyx was better.
As noted in their answer, it doesn't allow for cross-dependencies, but in my case I think the dependencies are only one-way (`Weight` may care about `Height`, but `Height` does not care about `Weight`), so that is not an issue.

Comment: Would't this work better with two parent classes?

Comment: Why do you need explicit instantation / specialization in 1st place? Can you elaborate about that please.

Comment: specializations dont "mix". Only one of your 5 definitions can be chosen for an instantiation. You might be interested in policy based design

Comment: @tadman The issue is that there will be resources required by both methods, and I wanted to avoid redefining the same method (e.g. to load in that resource) for both of the parent classes.

Comment: What do you mean by "resources required"? I've added an answer below, but with your edit I'm not clear if that's sufficient for your use case.

Comment: After having done a lot of Rust which has a fantastic pattern matching system it becomes obvious how much of a dead spot this is in C++.

Comment: @tadman [This](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1371r1.pdf) might interest you then. Fingers crossed for c++23 :)

Comment: @cigien I try not to get my hopes up, but still hyped about modules anyway!

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yes, you have hit the nail on the head regarding the issue. I am looking into policy based design now, and it does look like what I want; however, I would want the specializations to be able to access members of the primary class (e.g. if Person had member "name" which they included in their salutation).

Comment: @cigien I've made some edits that try to show how the different specializations depend on a common resource, but how the specialization along the weight dimension also involves two different variables. I'm not sure if this helps, but it should better reflect the end goal.

Comment: The solution below will work just fine with these additional requirements. I can add that to the answer if you like.

Comment: @cigien What if I want to later access either `show` or `goal`? (Assuming I know which one is a valid query.)

Comment: You can simply declare `name` and `goal` in whichever scope you need, and only use them in the branches they're needed in. Would that work for you?

Comment: "I would want the specializations to be able to access members of the primary class (e.g. if Person had member "name" which they included in their salutation" .. template specialization is not inheritance but you can combine them, eg you can have all `Person<T>` inherit from some base class

Comment: @idclev463035818 You're right about template specialization not being the same as inheritance... I think templates probably just aren't the right solution for this. I've updated the question with a solution that seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use inheritance to add degrees of freedom in functionality in "layers".

```
enum class Weight { Skinny, Fat };
enum class Height { Short, Tall };

struct PersonBase {
    const char* name = "name";
};

template<Weight W>
struct PersonWeight : PersonBase {
    void SayHello();
};

template<Weight W, Height H>
struct PersonHeight : PersonWeight<W> {
    void SayGoodbye();
};

template<Weight W, Height H>
struct Person : PersonHeight<W, H> {
};

template<>
struct PersonWeight<Weight::Skinny> : PersonBase {
    const char* goal = "ride a bike";
    void SayHello() {
        printf("Hello, I am skinny %s.\n", name);
        printf("My goal is to %s.\n", goal);
    }
};
template<>
struct PersonWeight<Weight::Fat> : PersonBase {
    const char* show = "movies";
    void SayHello() {
        printf("Hello, I am fat %s.\n", name);
        printf("My favorite show is %s.\n", show);
    }
};

template<Weight W>
struct PersonHeight<W, Height::Short> : PersonWeight<W> {
    void SayGoodbye() { printf("Goodbye, I am short %s.\n", name); }
};

template<Weight W>
struct PersonHeight<W, Height::Tall> : PersonWeight<W> {
    void SayGoodbye() { printf("Goodbye, I am tall %s.\n", name); }
};
```

This won't work if there's a cross-dependency between the layers though. In that case `if constexpr` or SFINAE might help.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use an `if` condition in your functions to decide what message to print, like this:

```
template<Weight W, Height H>
struct Person
{
    void SayHello(void) {
      if (W == Weight::Skinny)
        std::cout << "Hello, I am skinny.\n";
      else  
        std::cout << "Hello, I am fat.\n";
    }
    
    void SayGoodbye(void) {
      if (H == Height::Short)
        std::cout << "Goodbye, I am short.\n";
      else  
        std::cout << "Goodbye, I am tall.\n";
    }
};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fz97z4).

Comment: That's fair---in the real case, the specializations would also manage many different resources; all of the different combinations of specializations would be compatible with one another, but they would be more complicated than in the example.

Comment: If the different versions are compatible with one another, then this should work. You can of course refactor the body of the `if-else` branches to clean it up. If there is "incompatible" code in the :specializations" then `if constexpr` might work, but I'd have to see your use case.